# Entity framework along with plain old ADO.Net

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am building a new applications architecture and I need your advice. We have a central MSSQL server database hosted as SQL Azure. This database needs to be accessed from many different applications, most of them are web applications hosted in windows azure and couple of them are winforms apps.

Accessing database for web application is straight forward with ADO.Net. For winforms applications, the wcf data services technology seems impressive along with client authentication services for security.

I need to know whether this mixed mode of database access will work? In other words, will database integrity will be maintained if it is being hit by applications using a mix of ADO.Net and Entity framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going with WCF RIA services. They seem to work well with multiple client types providing out of the box data access layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you query the database using EntityFramework it will cache the data until you call SaveChanges(). If the database is modified (e.g. using plain old ADO.NET) in the meantime there is a risk of the data from the database being overriden by the application that is using Entity Framework. To prevent from this you need to use Concurrency Token. You can find some details here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3866.aspx
Note that when you start using concurrency tokens you need to be aware of possible concurrency exceptions which you need to handle. You can take a look at this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/02/17/handling-optimistic-concurrency-exception-with-ef-and-mvc-3.aspx for some ideas. WCF Data Services uses ETags for concurrency (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/22/optimistic-concurrency-data-services.aspx) but you may not need to do anything here if you setup concurrency in the EF model for the database that is exposed via WCF Data Services.